# Xamarin Error Parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xamarin

I've been looking at other answers on here to try and figure out my issue, however, I'm getting an error with no code actually added. I open a new project and added a Horizontal Scroll View and immediately got XML error without even changing anything myself, I then removed the code and I still get an error on line 11 even though my program is only 10 lines long.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"



   </RelativeLayout>
```

Somehow I'm getting an error on line 11 when this is 10 lines long. I still don't understand why as soon as I add something such as Horizontal Scroll View or some text it immediately decides to display an error.

Comment: @SebastianHofmann I've just brought it all down to one line after each other making a total of 7 lines and it still says there is an error on line 8 which doesn't exist so as far as I'm aware this is no line-break

Comment: You don't have a closing `>` on your `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative layout is missing `>`. It should look like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
```